# How many of each type of path cards are there in Saboteur?

Tags: saboteur

I lost 4 Saboteur path cards, and want to print my own versions as substitutes. However, I don't know which 4 cards I lost. How many of each type of path card are there in the game?

**Edit**
I managed to find a Saboteur card breakdown image with a count of each type of card (see [link](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/180040/saboteur)).

Here is my count based on that image.
Here is how to interpret the ASCII art: each card is represented by a 3x3 square, with `x` denoting that part of the card is filled with rocks.

```
x x         x x         x x         xxx         xxx
x x = 4     x   = 5         = 5     x   = 4       x = 5
x x         x x         x x         x x         x x

xxx         x x         x x         xxx         xxx
x x = 1      xx = 1      x  = 1     xx  = 1      xx = 1
x x         x x         x x         x x         x x

xxx         x x         xxx
  x = 1         = 5         = 3
xxx         xxx         xxx

x x         x x         xxx
xxx = 1         = 1      x  = 1
x x         xxx         xxx
```

This gives a total of 40 path cards. However, my manual indicates that there are 44 path cards, 27 action cards, 28 gold nugget cards, 7 miner cards and 4 saboteur cards. I only counted 40 path cards (excluding the start card with the ladder, and the 3 destination cards). Am I indeed missing 4 cards, or is the count given in the manual wrong?

Comment: My count of cards matches the count in the breakdown image. Perhaps I am not really missing any cards after all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing any.

As you can see, the treasure card ("la carte Arrivée avec le trésor") and the rock cards ("les cartes Arrivée avec des pierres") and the starting card ("carte de départ") are not listed in the contents. There are 40 "normal" path cards, or 44 when you include those four.

Comment: That's great to know that I'm not missing anything. I didn't realize that the 44 cards include the treasure card, the two rock cards and the starting card. Thanks!